# JSON string deserialization c# issue

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I found solution [JsonPropertyName("currentPage")] attributes should be added for each property or second and better solution add camelCaseOption like this

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
            };

            // Act
            var pagedResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PagedResult<UserDtoTest>>(jsonString, options);
```

I have those classes and I want to test if JSON string serialization and deserialization works properly, but test fails as pagedResult I get after deserialization on JSON string contains only default value.

```
public abstract class PagedResultBase
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; }
    public int ResultsPerPage { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }
    public long TotalResults { get; }

    protected PagedResultBase()
    {
    }

    protected PagedResultBase(int currentPage, int resultsPerPage,
        int totalPages, long totalResults)
    {
        CurrentPage = currentPage > totalPages ? totalPages : currentPage;
        ResultsPerPage = resultsPerPage;
        TotalPages = totalPages;
        TotalResults = totalResults;
    }
}
```

```
public class PagedResult<T> : PagedResultBase
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public bool IsEmpty => Items == null || !Items.Any();
    public bool IsNotEmpty => !IsEmpty;

    public PagedResult()
    {
        Items = new List<T>();
    }

    public PagedResult(List<T> items,
        int currentPage, int resultsPerPage,
        int totalPages, long totalResults) :
        base(currentPage, resultsPerPage, totalPages, totalResults)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public static PagedResult<T> Create(List<T> items,
        int currentPage, int resultsPerPage,
        int totalPages, long totalResults)
        => new(items, currentPage, resultsPerPage, totalPages, totalResults);

    public static PagedResult<T> From(PagedResultBase result, List<T> items)
        => new(items, result.CurrentPage, result.ResultsPerPage,
            result.TotalPages, result.TotalResults);

    public static PagedResult<T> Empty => new();
}
```

and

```
public class UserDtoTest
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [JsonPropertyName("active")]
            public bool Active { get; set; }
        }
```

when I try to deserialize json string it returns PagedResult with default values, any ideas? Here is my Test

```
[Fact]
        public void ReturnsPagedResultWithCorrectProperties()
        {
            // Arrange

            string jsonString = @"{
                  ""items"": [
                    {
                      ""name"": ""anatolijs"",
                      ""active"": true
                    },
                    {
                      ""name"": ""trololo"",
                      ""active"": true
                    },
                    {
                      ""name"": ""rindām"",
                      ""active"": true
                    },
                    {
                      ""name"": ""terepere"",
                      ""active"": true
                    }
                  ],
                  ""isEmpty"": false,
                  ""isNotEmpty"": true,
                  ""currentPage"": 1,
                  ""resultsPerPage"": 10,
                  ""totalPages"": 1,
                  ""totalResults"": 4
                }";
            
            // Act
            var pagedResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PagedResult<UserDtoTest>>(jsonString);
            var serializedJsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<PagedResult<UserDtoTest>>(pagedResult);

            // Assert
            jsonString.Should().Be(serializedJsonString);
        }
```

one constrain I have to use using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

Comment: Have a look if this might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism

Comment: And also this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconstructorattribute?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you don't have set in your base class , you can fix it

```
public abstract class PagedResultBase
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; init; }
    public int ResultsPerPage { get; init; }
    public int TotalPages { get; init; }
    public long TotalResults { get; init; }

    // ....another code

}
```

and you need different option is you want to get rid of PropertyName atribute

```
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };

    var pagedResult = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PagedResult<UserDtoTest>>(jsonString,options);
```